Different results from MP2 calculations on same geometry in ORCA
I am trying to do a segmented potential energy scan around a dihedral for a molecule. I have optimized the geometry to a minima, and the scan runs from [-180, 180] in steps of two points at a time.
This is the input file that I used to calculate the energies at $\phi = 170$ and $\phi = 160$. The initial coordinates for $\phi = 170$ was obtained from the previous scan of $\phi 
 \rightarrow [180, 170]$.
! Opt MP2 6-31g* PAL4
%geom Scan
D 5 0 1 2 = 170, 160, 2
end
end
*xyz 0 1
  C   -0.01296114269949      0.94440242563597     -0.29053248441691
  C    1.20359520080223      1.00137801653345      0.29786516905158
  C    2.43657224093117      1.07558212649403     -0.46404217200734
  C    3.67272330832435      0.98117376597373      0.06277543031523
  H   -0.10490902371364      1.11202620979905     -1.36291570524297
  N   -1.22131071498263      0.67701537644153      0.34966432355423
  H    1.28397084032817      0.83321545027387      1.37307026220526
  H    2.33425017243896      1.20438753874106     -1.54294877796397
  H    3.82735652201142      0.85397587500326      1.13084169769749
  H    4.55938381385145      1.02098202753128     -0.56055815416925
  H   -1.12997794903088      0.20498190250356      1.24205069378367
  H   -1.92086326826118      0.23860928506914     -0.23528028280703
*

As expected, the calculation of $\phi = 170$ completed in a single step (since it was already optimized in the last step). However, the energies that I obtained are different in both the cases.
 180.00000000 -210.60870348
 170.00000000 -210.60703037
===========================
 170.00000000 -210.60703059
 160.00000000 -210.60380225

What can be the reason for this difference? I know that the difference is in the 7th and 8th decimal places, but I would ideally like them to be same.

I cannot unfortunately use a better basis set because I am parameterizing this for CHARMM FF, and this is the recommended level of theory and basis set.

Using ORCA 5.0.4, I ran calculations based on the input file provided. As is, the orca.relaxscanact.dat list:
 180.00000000 -210.60870333 
 170.00000000 -210.60703035
###########################
 170.00000000 -210.60703059 
 160.00000000 -210.60380225 

I compared the nuclear repulsion energies (ENN) for the two relevant/final 170° structures and found:
154.428728248405
################
154.432470546304

which suggests that the relevant geometry optimizations started at different structures.
In the light of these results, I made the convergence tolerances more conservative (input file):
# ... snip
%geom
 convergence tight
 Scan
 D 5 0 1 2 = 180, 170, 2
 end
end
# snip ...

which yielded
 180.00000000 -210.60870351 
 170.00000000 -210.60703076 
###########################
 170.00000000 -210.60703076 
 160.00000000 -210.60380252 

For completeness, the '170°' ENN are:
154.433928524878
################
154.434477456670

so there is some deviation cancellation. The increase in computational time was around 20%, though that number does not extrapolate well to larger systems. Note that the convergence tight line can be substituted for more detailed (and tighter still) control of the geometry optimization criteria, though overdoing it leads to geometries flipping back and forth in my experience. If one is looking for curves to fit potentials, one may be better off running the curves forwards and backwards to use average results.

Have you confirmed that the geometries for each are exactly the same? If the second calculation took a single step, its possible it moved the geometry very slightly. ORCA's default convergence criteria for geometry optimizations includes a condition that the energies between steps should not differ by more than $1\times10^{-6}$ Hartree. So as far as at least the energy criteria is concerned, structures with energies differing by $1\times10^{-6}$ would also qualify as a minimum.
In general, when a QM program converges a geometry to a minimum, its not likely to be converging it to the exact/true local minimum for your level of theory. Rather, it is converging to one structure among many subtly different structures which all meet the convergence criteria for the optimizer. If the program chooses reasonable convergence criteria, these structures should be qualitatively and, for most use cases, even quantitatively consistent in terms of their properties.
Of course, there are some properties which depend more sensitively on the geometry and in those cases you may want to use even more stringent convergence criteria to ensure you are "close enough" to the true local minimum. But even in this case, you are just shrinking the acceptable convergence region and in practice you can never reduce it a single point representing the true/exact local minimum.

@Nike Dattani: Respectfully, to claim that orca was designed for mEh precision is completely wrong and highly misleading. You get just as accurate with it as with any other quantum chemistry program.
You say; "... just as there is not going to be a citation that says that ORCA was designed for micro-hartree precision"
ok, if you want a citation - I am the lead developer of ORCA - here is your citation: "ORCA was designed to be just as precise as any other quantum chemistry program, not just micro-Eh".
Of course, you can abuse ORCA to get lower accuracy, but that is universally true - every program, every method can get abused.  Like car drivers have a responsibility to drive their cars with care, users of quantum chemistry programs are not free of responsibility either.
btw - I just ran Li-atom/aug-cc-pCV5Z AUTOCI-CISDT and get an energy:
E(CISDT)= -7.477 431 663 800 Eh
First of all, it agrees to 0.1 micro-Eh with the other programs. Once one passes to a Davidson solver instead of a DIIS solver used to generate this number, it agrees to all digits with the other programs. (the DIIS solver here simply was not run to machine precision like the other programs did).
I kindly ask you to maybe be a bit more careful with such strong statements in the future. You do not want to have fake news and false information spread around about you and the same is true for us too. Apart from that, I second every word that wzkchem5 said. (and if TAR86 is who I hope they are - nice to meet you again!)

I am curious why that CISDT energy is 9 to 10 nano-Hartree below the result that was obtained by 3 separate programs. Not every aug-cc-pCV5Z basis set will be the same, as I know David Feller has re-optimized the exponents and contraction coefficients for many periodic table elements over the years. The exponents and contraction coefficients that were used in Molpro start at line 141 here.

The Molpro calculation had the integrals threshold set to 1e-18 and the energy threshold set to 1d-16: gthresh,oneint=1e-18,twoint=1e-18,THROVL=1e-11,THRORTH=2.d-6 THRESH,ENERGY=1d-16. The CFOUR calculation also usedXFORM_TOL=18, SCF_CONV=10, CCTOL=16 so the integrals threshold was 1e-18, the largest density difference for the SCF calculation was lower than 1e-10 and the CC threshold was 1e-16. For some reason the MRCC calculation used default settings.

To address your main concern though, the easiest thing for me to do at this hour of the day (it's around midnight here) was to delete my answer which claimed that ORCA was designed for milli-hartree precision :) .
